# Is it possible: Webpack without npm?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I started to develop a new project, where frontend is on react, backend is on java play. I don't use nodejs and npm.

I try to import component that i developed and get error "ReferenceError: require is not defined". As far as i understand, the solution is to combine all react jsx files to one, using tool like webpack.

Can it be achieved using webpack, without installing npm, with the help of maven and\or IntelliJ?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use NodeJS as your backend to use webpack. I have NodeJS installed on my system to perform this compilation step for a client app on a C# backend. Alternatively, you could use RequireJS to manage imports on the client.

Comment: Should i have npm installed? Can it be avoided?

Comment: I believe npm comes with NodeJS natively, but you don't have to use it.

Comment: No, you need npm for webpack.  If you want an alternative to webpack, you can try out browserify or jspm, both of which use npm. maven only contains packages for the JVM and IntelliJ is just an IDE. Neither of them can serve as replacements to the JavaScript package manager that is npm (or bower) /thread

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Practically speaking: no.

Webpack is a Node-based application, and to install and run it you need both Node and NPM.

Not only that, but for Webpack to do anything meaningful, it requires "loaders" that are Node modules which should be installed with NPM as well.

Lastly, when developing React apps, any external modules that your app will depend on (including React itself) should *also* be installed with NPM.

However, you don't need to install Node/NPM in your production environment. Webpack will generate JS-bundles that you can load into your HTML just as any regular JS script, and that part of the process doesn't require Node or NPM.

So you'll need it during development, but not in production.

Comment: Hmmm , so an application using Webpack can be hosted on apache, but needs to run with npm and have node installed? Im trying to setup a Vue.js app which webpack and springboot. Thanks!

Comment: @CoryTam you can typically run the build process (which creates the JS bundle) on another machine, and copy the bundle file to the server, which doesn't itself have to have Node.js/NPM/Webpack installed in that case.

Comment: It doesn't mean that it couldn't be possible. Those nodejs do have some specification somewhere, don't they? The server-side part could be re-written in kotlin or java.